# How to update MariaDB?

Tags: installation, 9

I was following Set up Demo Site for Theming Practice; then, I realized that, since Drupal 9 is out, by default Drupal 9 is installed instead of Drupa 8.x is installed when running `composer create-project drupal/recommended-project $SITE_NAME`.

So I continued along. I was fine, until I came to the install local site. I got this error:

> The database server version 10.2.31-MariaDB-1:10.2.31+maria~bionic-log is less than the minimum required version 10.3.7.

Since I'm using ddev and docker, does this mean I need to upgrade my MariaDB version used inside of my image? if so, how do I do that?

A step by step solution explaining each step would be really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need to update MariaDB. Just "cd" to your ddev project directory in the terminal and issue the following commands:

```
ddev config --mariadb-version=10.4
```

and then

```
ddev restart
```

That's it! Good luck:)